# Create a single.php template for custom database table records

Tags: php, wordpress

Is this possible to make a single.php template for displaying the data of custom database table? Like we have a single.php as a detail page for each post. So, the user will see all the entries on a page template offers.php. When he will click on the offer detail link, a new page will be opened which have all the details about offer.

(Updated)

Comment: what's the problem?you don't know sql?

Comment: your query is unclear. what seems to be the barrier

Comment: Is this possible to make a single.php template for displaying the data of custom database table? Like we have a single.php as a detail page for each post.

Comment: in wordpress, look for your theme folder. there you will find all custom cms pages. You can create your `single.php` in that folder itself. You need also to create a custom route for that as well. After that you can use wp global var to query your database... tell me if i'm getting it right, i'll post the long answer

Comment: @ZubairMushtaq,  Yes, this is possible to make a single.php but it's not good way to displaying the data of custom database table. I suggest to you that you can create one new custom template page and you can manage the custom functionality in custom template page.

Comment: @chandlerbing Thank you very much. Kindly, guide me about custom route. I have a page name with Package and template for this is package.php. In the following URL http://localhost/mobile-packages/package/xyz-data-package, xyz-data-package is the package slug in DB. I want to query the package detail by this slug on the pakcage age. How can I handle it with routing becasue it gives 404 error on visiting this page.

Comment: @ZubairMushtaq, ya you can try steps as dipak shared. Otherwise, I have other solution. I will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use your custom table, if it is really necessary to use. No issues at all.
2. Create [Custom Post Type](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) and if do not want to show that post type in admin menu then you can keep that hidden.
3. While saving the post apart from inserting to your table just create new post with the custom post type created earlier. Use `wp_inset_post` to create Wp post. [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)
4. So now a record in Custom Table and a Post in WP Posts table. Create a post_meta named as "custom_linked_id" or whatever you may like and update the Custom Tables Inserted ID to the WP POST.

> update_post_meta( $WP_POST_ID, 'custom_linked_id',
>   $CUSTOM_TABLE_INSERT_ID);

5. Now create single page for your new custom post type. Page name structure is single-{cpt}.php. By default you will get your single post here.
6. Just inside the loop get the related custom ID by calling the post_meta. So sample code will be like,

> $custom_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'custom_linked_id', true );

7. Now using that ID you can get all your data from custom table.

**Note**

Columns used in your custom table can be stored as meta values, it is very easy to achieve and effective.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Dipak guru. I hope it will solve this problem. I am going to implement it. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For custom route. Install this plugin called `WP Route.` Go into your theme folder where you'll find all sorts of static php files like 404.php, header.php, etc. Create `package.php` there. Open you fav editor with `functions.php` in the same folder and enter the following content:

```
function create_routes( $router ) {
$router->add_route('package', array(
'path' => 'mobile-packages/package/xyz-data-package',
'access_callback' => true,
'page_callback' => 'updatefunction'
));

 }
add_action( 'wp_router_generate_routes', 'create_routes' );

function updatefunction() {

load_template(get_template_directory() . '/package.php', true );
exit();
}
```

Open up `404.php` file in the same folder and copy theme settings like `get_header()` and `get_footer()` to `package.php`

Let me know if there's anything missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this kind help. Let me test with this. Thanks chandlerbing